# Why do these SaltStack functions have different output?

Tags: shell, salt-stack

I'm new to SaltStack and ran these two command:

```
# salt '*' test.echo "$PWD"
# salt '*' cmd.run "pwd"
```

I have got different output!
Does anyone know what is the difference between two above command?

I expected the same result for both commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a shell command, first any shell expansions are processed, then the command is executed.

For the first command it expands `"$PWD"` to the current working directory of the shell, then instructs all minions to run e.g. `test.echo('/home/mhm')`.

For the second command it instead instructs all minions to run `cmd.run('pwd')`, which returns the current working directory of the minion service.